# Jetson TK1 booting issues

Tags: linux, nvidia, tegra

Received my Jetson TK1 yesterday. After unboxing it and configuring the Linux GUI, rebooting the device with a mouse (cordless) attached to its USB 3.0 port takes it to some sort of Command line page where it probably loads some files and then the screen starts printing " [ . ] ". Nothing happens beyond that until I restart the board without any USB peripheral and then the device boots into the normal Linux GUI. Unable to figure out what's wrong with my board and why is it not working properly.(I am a newbie to LINUX)

P.S.: Connecting the monitor via HDMI after switching on the device gives no visual output, just a blank screen. Is it possible to connect the device via network adapter for remote access even it the screen is running blank?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with CUDA, so removing the CUDA tag.  If you feel otherwise, add it back.  It's not clear to me this is a programming issue either.  It may be off-topic for SO.  However, as in your previous question, there are plenty of other online resources for Jetson support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is quite old, but as some people might get frustrated with it, I'll provide the answer for most probable cause.

Upgrading the board running **19.X** release causes `libglx.so` to be corrupted. The issue have been actively [discussed](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/747574/embedded-systems/jetson-tk1-boot-issue/post/4307741/#4307741) on NVIDIA forums and the best way to solve it is to **upgrade to 21.X**.

Otherwise, you can [try recovering](http://iamtawit.blogspot.se/2014/09/jetson-tk1-boot-problem-issue-with.html) the `libglx.so` in the `usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/` from `Tegra124_Linux_R19.3.0_armhf.tbz2`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly provide a bit more information about your situation.

Are you able to go to command mode by pressing 'CTRL+F1' or 'CTRL+ALT+F1'? 
If that works, it means your Jetson operating system is working but only the GUI is not working properly.

Yes, You can use ssh to your Jetson (what I do) if only the GUI of Jetson is broken and your OS is working properly. Note that in order to do so you need to know ip address of your Jetson and perform some possible router configuration.

Note: Sometimes if you have a USB device connected to your system (jetson), the jetson might mistakenly assume the USB is storage type and therefore tries to boot up from the USB. This leads to failure since it can not load any OS of the USB. (I'm not sure if this is the case for you)